# Repository Pattern + Dependancy Injection + UnitOfWork + EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

There are a lot of similar questions to this on S/O, but this one has a specific issue that I have not see addressed:

This is an MVC application. I am using Dependancy injection (Simple Injector, though I think it is irrelevant), it injects the Per Web Request.

The main problem I am having is that because my UoW is injected per web request, I am unable to fail and continue when adding data, which I recently have had need of.

The following code illustrates:

**Data Layer**

```
public abstract RepositoryBase<TEntity>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    //fields set from contrstuctor injection
    protected RepositoryBase(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(Int32 id)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }
}

public UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository
{
    //constructor injection
    public UserRepository(MyDbContext c) : base(c) {}

    public Update(Int32 id, String name, String email, Int32 ageYears)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        entity.Name = name;
        entity.Email = email;
        entity.Age = ageYears;
    }

    public UpdateName(Int32 id, String name)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        entity.Name = name;
    }
}

public AddressRepository : RepositoryBase<Address>, IAddressRepository
{
    //constructor injection
    public AddressRepository(MyDbContext c) : base(c) {}

    public Update(Int32 id, String street, String city)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        entity.Street = street;
        entity.City = city;
    }

    public Address GetForUser(Int32 userId)
    {
        return _context.Adresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId = userId);
    }
}

public DocumentRepository : RepositoryBase<Document>, IDocumentRepository
{
    //constructor injection
    public DocumentRepository(MyDbContext c) : base(c) {}

    public Update(Int32 id, String newTitle, String newContent)
    {
        var entity.GetById(id);
        entity.Title = newTitle;
        entity.Content = newContent;
    }

    public IList<Document> GetForUser(Int32 userId)
    {
        return _context.Documents.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
    }
}

public UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    //fields set from contrstuctor injection
    public UnitOfWork(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Int32 Save()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public ITransaction StartTransaction()
    {
        return new Transaction(_context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted));
    }
}

public Transaction : ITransaction
{
    private readonly DbContextTransaction _transaction;

    public Transaction(DbContextTransaction t)
    {
        _transaction = t;
        State = TransactionState.Open;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_transaction != null)
        {
            if (State == TransactionState.Open)
            {
                Rollback();
            }
            _transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public TransactionState State { get; private set; }

    public void Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            _transaction.Commit();
            State = TransactionState.Committed;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            State = TransactionState.FailedCommitRolledback;
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (_transaction.UnderlyingTransaction.Connection != null)
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
        }
        State = TransactionState.Rolledback;
    }
}
```

**Service Layer**

```
public DocumentService : IDocumentService
{
    //fields set from contrstuctor injection
    private readonly IDocumentRepository _docRepo;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public void AuthorNameChangeAddendum(Int32 userId, String newAuthorName)
    {
        //this works ok if error thrown
        foreach(var doc in _docRepo.GetForUser(userId))
        {
            var addendum = $"\nAddendum: As of {DateTime.Now} the author will be known as {newAuthorName}.";
            _docRepo.Update(documentId, doc.Title + "-Processed", doc.Content + addendum);
        }
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}

public UserService
{
    //fields set from contrstuctor injection
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;
    private readonly IAddressRepository _addressRepo;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IDocumentService _documentService;

    public void ChangeUser(Int32 userId, String newName, String newStreet, String newCity)
    {
        //this works ok if error thrown
        _userRepo.UpdateName(userId, newName);

        var address = _addressRepo.GetForUser(userId);
        _addressRepo.Update(address.AddressId, newStreet, newCity);

        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    public void ChangeUserAndProcessDocs(Int32 userId, String newName, Int32)
    {
        //this is ok because of transaction
        using(var transaction = _unitOfWork.StartTransaction())
        {
            _documentService.AuthorNameChangeAddendum(userId, newName); //this function calls save() on uow

            //possible exception here could leave docs with an inaccurate addendum, so transaction needed
            var x = 1/0;

            _userRepo.UpdateName(userId, newName);

            _unitOfWork.Save();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    //THE PROBLEM: 
    public IList<String> AddLastNameToAll(String lastName)
    {
        var results = new List<String>();
        foreach(var u in _userRepo.GetAll())
        {
            try
            {
                var newName = $"{lastName}, {u.Name}";
                _userRepo.UpdateName(u.UserId, newName);
                _unitOfWork.Save(); //throws validation exception 
                results.Add($"Changed name from {u.Name} to {newName}.");
            }
            catch(DbValidationException e)
            {
                results.Add($"Error adding last name to {u.Name}: {e.Message}");
                //but all subsequeqnet name changes will fail because the invalid entity will be stuck in the context
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

You can see in the UserService that the UoW implementation handles `ChangeUser()`, and the potential problem in `ChangeUserAndProcessDocs()` is handled by the use of an explicit transaction.

But in `AddLastNameToAll()` the problem is that if I have 100 users to update and the 3rd one fails because the Name column is not long enought to handle the new name, then results 3 throught 100 will all have the same validation message in them. The only way to solve this is to use a new UnitOf Work (DbContext) for each pass of the for loop, which is not really possible with my implementation.

My UoW+Repo implementation prevents leaking EF into other layers, and does give other layers the ability to create a transaction. But it has always felt weird that if A Service calls B Service, the the B service could call Save() before A was ready. The scoped transaction solves that, but still feels a little odd.

I thought of scrapping UoW pattern, and just having all my repository actions commit immediately, but this leave the gaping issue of updating two different enttity types and having the 2nd update fail, but the first update that succeeded does not make sense now (see `ChangeUserAndProcessDocs()` is an example.

So I am left with making a special `UpdateName()` function on the UserRepository `UpdateNameImmediately()` that ignores the injected context and creates it's own.

```
    public void UpdateNameImmediately(Int32 id, String newName)
    {
        using(var mySingleUseContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
             var u = mySingleUseContext.Users.Find(id);
             u.Name = newName;
             mySingleUseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This feels odd, because now this function behaves quite differently that all my other repository actions, and would not obey the transaction.

Is there an implementatin of UoW + EF + Repository Pattern + DI that solves this?

Comment: Did you know that EF implements the UoW and Repo pattern by default? The DbContext is a UoW and the DbSet is the Repos. My Point; adding more abstraction to EF is a waste of time.

Comment: I was aware that DbContext is a UoW. I only thin wrapper on it to avoid leaking EF into service layers. The repo wrapper around it helps me to funnel everything my through a few repository actions, and police bad joins etc. If there is a better way to accomplish those things I am open to hearing it.

Comment: The issue presented in AddLastNameToAll() actually occurs in a pretty specialised Service that does almost all bulk processing. I am leaning towards just creating a couple specialised 'ImmediateRepositories' that do not use the UoW pattern. I think this is likely the simplest.

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/RajKarri/Generic-Repository You might need to look at https://github.com/RajKarri/Generic-Repository/blob/master/GenRep/Repository/Repositories/EntityFrameworkRepository.cs and https://github.com/RajKarri/Generic-Repository/blob/master/GenRep/Repository/Contexts/EntityFrameworkContext.cs classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for `AddLastNameToAll()` to have it commit each change immediately was an 'immediate repository wrapper'. This allowed me to reuse my existing code, and allowed me to continue to easily mock repository behaviour when testing my servies.  The an example immediate repository wrapper for the users looks like this:

```
public interface IUserImmediateRepository
{
    void UpdateName(Int32 id, String newName);
}

public class UserImmediateRepository : IUserImmediateRepository
{
    public UserImmediateRepository()
    {
    }

    public void UpdateName(Int32 id, String newName)
    {
        using(var singleUseContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var repo = new UserRepository(singleUseContext);
            repo.UpdateName(id, newName);
            singleUseContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

This has worked very well for the rare scenario of bulk processing, where I need immediate commits.

Answer (score 0):

**How it works:**

```
  public class DbFactory : Disposable, IDbFactory
    {
        HomeCinemaContext dbContext;



 public HomeCinemaContext Init()
    {
        return dbContext ?? (dbContext = new HomeCinemaContext());
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (dbContext != null)
            dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly IDbFactory dbFactory;
        private HomeCinemaContext dbContext;

        public UnitOfWork(IDbFactory dbFactory)
        {
            this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
        }

        public HomeCinemaContext DbContext
        {
            get { return dbContext ?? (dbContext = dbFactory.Init()); }
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            DbContext.Commit();
        }
    }

 public class EntityBaseRepository<T> : IEntityBaseRepository<T>
            where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
    {

        private HomeCinemaContext dataContext;

        #region Properties
        protected IDbFactory DbFactory
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        protected HomeCinemaContext DbContext
        {
            get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DbFactory.Init()); }
        }
        public EntityBaseRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory)
        {
            DbFactory = dbFactory;
        }
        #endregion
        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return DbContext.Set<T>();
        }
        public virtual IQueryable<T> All
        {
            get
            {
                return GetAll();
            }
        }
        public virtual IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = DbContext.Set<T>();
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
            return query;
        }
        public T GetSingle(int id)
        {
            return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }
        public virtual IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return DbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry<T>(entity);
            DbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry<T>(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry<T>(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }
```

Main class is DbFactory, it contains **ONLY one instance of EF db context**. So what ever you do in differerent repositories, application always uses ONE context.

Class EntityBaseRepository also works **on the same db context**, provided by DbFactory.

UnitOfWork is passed to controller only to be able to save all changes to database with method Commit, woorking on the same instance of db context.

You probalby dont need Transaction you use in your code.

**Full tutorial is here:**

https://chsakell.com/2015/08/23/building-single-page-applications-using-web-api-and-angularjs-free-e-book/#architecture\

Find words: "DbFactory" or "UnitOfWork" to get into details.

Comment: Pretty sure you want _one DB context per **unit of work**_ not one context for the entire app.  What happens if the connection breaks?

Comment: Not per application, but per user/request. It should be done by IOC container.

Comment: That's not what you say by _"...DbFactory, it contains ONLY one instance of EF db context...application always uses ONE context"_ and the injected `IDbFactory` is always going to return the same instance via  `DbFactory.Init`.  You need to show how lifetime of the factory is governed and then I probably would not call it a _factory_.  Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM

Comment: ok:), You are right. So it needs some change. It needs rather one instance per user/request. It would be done by IOC and object-per-request definition.

Comment: That's the ticket my friend :)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this is very similar to what I have. Rather than using a factory, I am simply using injection to share the context across my repo's and UoW.  Without the Transaction I don't see you your solution prevents the pitfall I demonstrate in UserService.ChangeUserAndProcessDocs(). And I don't see how it solves the issue I am trying to solve right now, which I demonstrate in UserService.AddLastNameToAll().